# How to send HTML from Selenium using sendKeys

Tags: python, html, wordpress, selenium, automation

I have a HTML code that I made using -

```
find_all(["h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "ul", "p", "h6"])
```

So, it has code like below -

```
<p>Hello this is a paragraph</p>
<h2>This is a Sub Heading</h2>
```

I want to send this whole HTML using send keys to my Wordpress post, but it returns the error

```
return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 0
```

If I use .text or .contents, I can send, however it removes the HTML tags. I want to send them including the tags, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it's working on here :

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
html_text = """
<p>Hello this is a paragraph</p>
<h2>This is a Sub Heading</h2>
"""

search.send_keys(html_text)
```

maybe the problem is on text treatment

Comment: I scrap the HTML from a site so if I use f"""{scrapped_html}""" it should work. Thanks, however I found out another answer that worked well, i.e. to simply convert it in string...